# Django: MongoDB engine for Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Anybody know of any currently worked on projects that wire up MongoDB to the most recent version of Django? mongoengine's Django module github hasn't been updated in 2 years (and I don't know if I can use its regular module with Django) and django-nonrel uses Django 1.6. Anybody tried using django-nonrel with Django 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoengine, there is no need of django-nonrel.You can directly use django latest versions.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I was just providing the two (django-nonrel and mongoengine) comparatively. So I can use mongoengine by itself, not its submodule "django-mongoengine"? I'm confused as to how mongoengine works with Django, do my model classes inherit from `Document` and `models.Model`? Like this for example: `class Thing(models.Model, Document): ...`?

Comment: You can see here http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#getting-started whatever you are asking :)

Comment: class Thing(Document),

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention anything about Django and if I structured my Django model as `class Thing(Document)`, how does Django know that it is a model?

Comment: Monogengine has its own queries like django ORM.  http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html

Comment: Ah yes I see, thank you. Lastly then, in my `settings.py`, I'm guessing I would add `mongoengine` under `INSTALLED_APPS`, but then what do I put for `DATABASES` dictionary for key `default` (like `ENGINE`)? The documentation just uses the `connect()` method.

Comment: DATABASES=whatever there.Dont worry about it.It will use only when class Thing(models.Model) is used.Also there is no migration for mongoengine.So no makemigration commands.

Comment: Okay great just wanted to make sure, and yes the migrations is the main reason I'm using Mongo haha. Thank you so much for all the help